# Laravel Testing Service Dependency Injection Error

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

To start from the conclusion, I get this error:

```
[ErrorException]                                                                                                                                                                                    
Argument 1 passed to SomeValidatorTest::__construct() must be an instance of App\Services\Validators\SomeValidator, none given, called in ....vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestSuite.php on line 475 and defined
```

In Laravel app, I have a script called "SomeValidator.php" which looks like this:

```
<?php namespace App\Services\Validators;

use App\Services\SomeDependency;

class SomeValidator implements ValidatorInterface
{

    public function __construct(SomeDependency $someDependency)
    {
        $this->dependency = $someDependency;
    }

    public function someMethod($uid)
    {
       return $this->someOtherMethod($uid);
    }

}
```

which runs without error.

Then the test script, SomeValidatorTest.php looks like this:

```
<?php

use App\Services\Validators\SomeValidator;


class SomeValidatorTest extends TestCase
{
    public function __construct(SomeValidator $validator)
    {
        $this->validator = $validator;
    }

    public function testBasicExample()
    {
        $result = $this->validator->doSomething();
    }
}
```

The error shows up only when the test script is ran through './vendor/bin/phpunit' The test class seems to be initiated without the dependency stated and throws an error. Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot inject classes into the tests (as far as i know), given that they are not resolved automatically by laravel/phpUnit.

The correct way is to `make` (resolve) them through laravel's `app` facade. Your test script should look like this:

```
<?php

class SomeValidatorTest extends TestCase
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->validator = \App::make('App\Services\Validators\SomeValidator');
    }

    public function testBasicExample()
    {
        $result = $this->validator->doSomething();
    }
}
```

Source: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/container