# Laravel Unit Testing Dependency Injection

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, phpunit

I'm trying to write a test class for a shopping cart. Here is what I have:

*ShoppingCartTest.php*

```
class ShoppingCartTest extends TestCase {

    use DatabaseTransactions;

    protected $shoppingCart;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->shoppingCart = resolve('App\Classes\Billing\ShoppingCart');
    }

    /** @test */
    public function a_product_can_be_added_to_and_retrieved_from_the_shopping_cart() {

        // just a placeholder at the moment
        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }

}
```

However, when I run phpunit, it seems like Laravel is unable to resolve my ShoppingCartClass.

Here is the error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException'
with message 'Unresolvable dependency resolving
[Parameter #0 [ <required> $app ]] in class Illuminate\Support\Manager'
in C:\Development Server\EasyPHP-Devserver-16.1\eds-www\nrponline\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:850
```

I have my ShoppingCart class being resolved in a number of different controllers just fine.

**Why can't Laravel resolve it during my tests?**

I refered to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33363499/laravel-testing-service-dependency-injection-error) as well but still didn't have any luck.

Comment: Could you post the constructor for `App\Classes\Billing\ShoppingCart` please?

Comment: @edcs Sure thing. Here is the class. http://pastebin.com/bPRpmtnH

Comment: Cool - thanks! You could try using `$this->app->make('App\Classes\Billing\ShoppingCart');` as all Laravel tests have an instance of the application available to them as a property.

Comment: @edcs Thanks for the response. I tried with `$this->app->make('App\Classes\Billing\ShoppingCart')` and am now getting a new error. **Fatal error: Call to a member function make() on null**

Comment: Just looking at one of my own projects, I never use `__construct()` to create instances of things. Try renaming `__construct()` to `setupShoppingCart()` (or similar - the name doesn't matter) and create a docblock which has `@before` in it, like this:

    /**
     * @before
     */

Comment: @edcs Thanks. See my answer below.

Comment: Glad you sorted it!

Answer (score 61, accepted):

I figured it out. Here is the updated class.

```
class ShoppingCartTest extends TestCase {

    use DatabaseTransactions;

    protected $shoppingCart;

    public function setUp() {

        parent::setUp();

        $this->shoppingCart = $this->app->make('App\Classes\Billing\ShoppingCart');
    }

    /** @test */
    public function a_product_can_be_added_to_and_retrieved_from_the_shopping_cart() {

        // just a placeholder at the moment
        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }

}
```

Thanks to [@edcs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/437704/edcs) for guiding me in the right direction.
You need to use a setUp function and not `__construct` as the `app` instance hasn't been created yet.

Comment: You should use `setUpBeforeClass()` if you want to execute the code only once like `__construct()` usually does

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `__construct` you have to use the same constructor of `PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase` and remember to call the parent method if you don't want to break anything

```
class MyTest extends TestCase
{
    public function __construct($name = null, array $data = [], $dataName = '')
    {
        parent::__construct($name, $data, $dataName);

        // my init code
    }
}
```

However the proper way would be to use the method `setUpBeforeClass()` if you want to execute your init code once or `setUp()` if you want to execute the init code before each test contained in your class.
Check [PHPUnit documentation](https://phpunit.de/manual/6.5/en/fixtures.html#fixtures.more-setup-than-teardown) for more details.

Comment: I initially had `__construct(...$args) { parent::__construct(...$args); ... }` and it failed for tests with data providers. This worked.